# Understanding I/O memory location in embedded C

Tags: c, pointers, embedded

• Declare a pointer,

```
int *p;
```

• Assign the address of the I/O memory location to the
pointer

```
 p = (int*) 0x30610000;
```

I want to to access the memory location `0x30610000` which has a register i want to configure.
Why should we type cast it? shouldn't `p =0x30610000;`  point to the location?.

Comment: Try to compile without the cast and see what the compiler says.

Comment: "initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast ".  Im not able to understand why it works when i type cast it.

Comment: okay, i understand the concept why we need to typecast pointers . In this, the RHS is an address i want to access ,why would it not work without casting it.  What i could find was that ,initially the hex value is a number, type casting is to make it an address. I was hoping for a bit more elaborate explanation.

Comment: `0x30610000` is an integer.  Assigning an integer to a pointer is usually an error, and at the very least should generate a compiler warning.  Explicitly casting it to a pointer indicates to the compiler that you want it to be interpreted as a pointer, and that it's not just a bug (as it normally would be).  So, it does exactly what you want it to do.

Comment: [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int *p;`

`p = (int*) 0x30610000;`

The method and the realisation are not good.

1. Use macros (not pointer variables) to access hardware registers mapped into the address space. It is the more efficient way.
2. Use fixed sizes integers.
3. Declare registers as `volatile`. They are side effects prone for sure :)

```
#define  REG1  (*(volatile uint32_t *)0x30610000)
```

and usage:

```
REG1 = 0x456;
foo(REG1);
```

Most peripherals have more than one register. It is good to use structs to access them (note the where `volatile` keywords are. Do not make the whole structure `volatile`):

```
typedef struct
{
    volatile uint32_t DR;
    volatile uint32_t CR;
    volatile uint32_t SR;
}UART_type;

#define UART1 ((UART_type *)0x45678000)
```

and usage:

```
UART1 -> CR = 0x45676;
```

In C language the cast is needed to silence the warning as it is an UB (or maybe only implementation defined as @Clifford suggested). Even if the implementation (like ARM-gcc) does it predictable way - it will still emit the warning.

Now, why having a pointer object is less efficient than `#define`. It is because the compiler needs more instructions to retrieve the address of the register.

Comment: Surely it is _implementation defined_ rather then _undefined_ behaviour?  Such conversions depend on the compiler, but should be consistent with the addressing structure of the system on which the compiled executable runs.

Comment: @Clifford probably you are right. Added it to the answer.

Comment: thanks for the extra tips. I mainly got confused as to why the compiler wont treat hex value as  an address without type-casting it .  Just to clear things up , its not possible to do something like          `int *p=0x30001000`  and expect `p` to be a pointer to the `0x30001000`.

Comment: It's implementation defined as per C17 6.3.2.3/5 "An integer may be converted to any pointer type. Except as previously specified, the result is implementation-defined, might not be correctly aligned, might not point to an entity of the referenced type, and might be a trap representation.". _However_ this is under the assumption that the compiler is completely unaware of what's stored at that location. In case the compiler thinks some other variable with a different type is stored there, you get strict aliasing UB. Which is mostly a problem with gcc.

Comment: Overall I prefer to do `#define UART1_CR (*(volatile uint32_t*)0x45678000u)` with individual registers and a prefix corresponding to the peripheral. Leaves out all potential hiccups with alignment, padding and strict aliasing.

Comment: @Lundin IMO it is more error prone if you have 10 UARTS having 15 registers each and you make a mistake in one address. IMO your way is more error prone and very inconvenient. Interesting how long you will write your headers for STM32H7?

Comment: @0___________ When writing register maps manually in the past, I've usually made a little PC prog that reads the register map from the manual and translates it to C code.

Comment: @0___________ No but neither does the silicon vendor who made you the pre-made register maps...

Comment: @Lundin you have never used the NRF uCs for sure :). Not using their definitions is a suicidal attempt. There is even errata to the errata :)

Comment: As for multiple peripherals that should use the same code, there's also this old trick: `#define UART_DR(base) (*(base + 1))` where `base` is something like `UART1`, `#define UART1 ((volatile uint32_t*)0x45678000u)`. You'd then write your driver like `void uart_send(uart_t base, ...) { UART_DR(base) = ...; }` and use the same code for all the 10 peripherals with the same register map.

Comment: @Lundin IMO it makes no sense at all. Most vendors think the same. If you see other programmers code they mostly use structures. But for sure they are all wrong and you are right. EOD as it is 100% opinion based.

Comment: @0___________ Using structures is fine if you never port between compilers, or intend to be portable between compilers. I do occasionally have such requirements and then structures (especially the ones using bit-fields) are trouble.

Comment: @Lundin `especially the ones using bit-fields`. Did I mention bitfields in my answer?

Comment: @Lundin `I do occasionally have such requirements and then structures` We use 4 compilers : IAR, gcc-arm, keil & GH. Projects have to compile using all. No problems at all.

Comment: @0___________ No. Did I mention NRF, silicon erratas etc etc in any of my comments?

Comment: Erratas are related to your comments. Bitfields are not.